# Visual Studio relative path issue with non standard project extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to import a targets file from a relative path. The targets file is containing version information. The goal is not to have to modify all the thousands of projects files that we have when we create a new branch and have a new assembly version. We need the assembly versions because 2 version of the system can be installed at the same time and we have dlls in the global assembly cache.

Here's what it looks like in the project file:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\..\..\..\..\..\Versions.targets" />
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="MyDll, Version=$(VersionAssemblies), Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
            <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Apps\$(CodeVersion)\DEVP\appl\BinApps\MyDll.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

This is working fine if I'm working with a .vbproj. But the issue is that we have a lot of old .cobproj Cobol project files. For some reason, it seems like Visual Studio 2010 don't set the working directory when opening a cobproj, so it's unable to reach Versions.targets...

If I rename my cobproj to use vbproj as extension, it's working fine. So it's definitively something that Visual Studio is doing when a project of a known extension is opened, but I've searched a lot and I didn't find where I could add cobproj to tell Visual Studio that it's a known extension.

Another interesting fact, it that if I double click on my cobproj, it's working, because the working directory is already set to the directory in which the cobproj is... If I open Visual Studio and then do a File/Open and select my cobproj, then it's not working.

I'm wondering if someone may know how I could fix my issue without changing the extention of all my cobproj. I'd like a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmya, `..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\` is a relative path from hell.  It of course won't work unless you reproduce the *exact* folder structure, all 10 and 6 levels deep.  Best to get rid of those cobwebs completely.

Comment: The folder structure is never the source of the problem in my case. It's standard within the company and it's created by a homemade tool. The only problem is the starting point, the working directory. This is what I need to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, if I modify the Project Type Guid in the .sln, I can make Visual Studio act with my .cobproj like it would with a .vbproj, at least regarding the working directory setting.

From the .sln file:

Project("{**F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F**}") = "appsEXCI.Donnees.Containers.Cobol", "appsEXCI.Donnees.Containers.Cobol.cobproj", "{54E1DEC4-8919-40F6-B7BB-C936921B221F}"
EndProject